# Алгоритм секундомера с миллисекундами запаздывает

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

```
 while (running) {
                        while (!pauseGame) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            }
                            millisecond++;
                            if (minutes != 0)
                                System.out.print(minutes + ".");
                            System.out.print(seconds + ".");
                            System.out.println(millisecond);
                            if (millisecond == 999) {
                                millisecond = -1;
                                seconds++;
                            }
                            if (seconds == 59) {
                                seconds = -1;
                                minutes++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Через 10 сек уже запаздывает на пару секунд. Если же задать `Thread.sleep(1000);` то всё работает как надо. Я делаю вывод, что время на остановку потока и на его возобновление довольно таки велико, чтобы каждую долю секунду этим заниматься. Я прав? Ну и как быть ? нужно и миллисекунды выводить.
В результате выполнения секундомера мне нужно  временя в численном значении, а не в виде изображения которое выводит объект chronometer в андроид студио.

Comment: а нельзя не самому считать число милисекунд через ++ а использовать системное время (его разность). Тогда в среднем всё будет правильно.

Comment: можно, но я не знаю как. Это я и хочу получить в ответе, например через каждые 0.1 секунды я хочу запрашивать время и получать сколько прошло миллисекунд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы было точно, надо выводить разность текущего времени с временем запуска.

А sleep вообще гарантирует только то, что пройдёт не меньше времени, чем указано.

Comment: логично, что не меньше чем указано. Для подсчета секунд этого достаточно. Ну сейчас попробую следить за системным временем

Comment: Лучше считать от System.currentTimeMillis() или System.nanoTime() ?  Хоть и  в первом варианте время уже в миллисекунда , второй вариант чем то лучше, а чем не помню

Comment: Не джавист, не знаю... Возможно, из второго можно получить с большей точностью.